# Playing an online match with a friend

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

My friend and I both have CSGO and wanted to play together.
When I click "play with friends" it creates a new lobby with just me and my friend in it.

I wanted to play a regular game with my friend, not just a 1v1 scenario. We'd like to play with others online.

**How do I get into an online match with my friend?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new lobby is what you want to do. From there you can choose what gamemode you want to play. The lobby just shows who you're queuing up with.

Comment: So if it that lobby it's me and him we will just be put into a random battle? Will we have to be in the same team or can we choose

Comment: It depends. If the gamemode is competitive, you'll be on the same team. If it's anything else though, you can choose teams once you get in the game.